# Web3JS sendTransaction to call function in contract

Tags: transactions, web3js

It is the first time I do this so I have no idea what I am doing !
I am trying to call a contract's function and post data to it, this contract will then create another contract. Here is my contract how my contract looks like:

```
contract MedicalStaffObject {
    using strings for *;
    event LogCreatedTrip(address);

    struct medicalStaffDetails {
       string phoneNumber;
       string physicalAddress;
    }

    medicalStaffDetails public details;
    address[] public trips;
    address public orgAddresses; 

    function MedicalStaffObject (address orgAddress, string phoneNumber, string physicalAddress){
        details.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        details.physicalAddress = physicalAddress;
        orgAddresses = orgAddress;
    }

    function getDetails() public constant returns (string, string, address){
        return (details.phoneNumber, details.physicalAddress, orgAddresses);
    }

    function getTrips() public constant returns (address[]){
        return (trips);
    }

    function newTrip(address zone1, address zone2, address zone3, address zone4, bytes32 name, bytes32 startingDate, uint duration) public returns(address){
        TripObject newTrip = new TripObject(zone1, zone2, zone3, zone4, name, startingDate, duration);
        trips.push(newTrip);
        LogCreatedTrip(newTrip);
        return newTrip;
    }
}
```

And I am trying to call the function newTrip using this code in my NodeJS app:

```
 var web3 = new Web3();
    web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider(provider));
    var zonesTrimed = zones.slice(1, -1);
    var zonesArray = zonesTrimed.split(",");

    var contractAbi = web3.eth.contract(ethContracts.abiMedicalStaffObject);
    var myContract = contractAbi.at(address);
    // suppose you want to call a function named newTrip of myContract
    var getData = myContract.newTrip.getData(zonesArray[0], zonesArray[1], zonesArray[2], zonesArray[3], name, startDate, duration);
    //finally paas this data parameter to send Transaction
    web3.eth.sendTransaction({to:address, from:organisationWallet, data: getData});
```

However it just doesnt work and I keep getting this error:

```
Error: unknown account
```

First of all what does this error mean, does it mean it cann't find the 'to' or the 'from' account ? What I am supposed to put in there ?

Comment: If you want to call newTrip function, you can do that like this : `myContract.newTrip.sendTransaction(zonesArray[0], zonesArray[1], zonesArray[2], zonesArray[3], name, startDate, duration, {from: web3.eth.coinbase, value : 120000})` Try this and let me know the result.

Comment: This works perfect ! however now i get this error:  Error: authentication needed: password or unlock I assum this has something to do with the account im using being locked but I am not sure how to deal with it

Comment: Unlock your account using `personal.unlockAccount(eth.coinbase, 'your password', duration)` on your node

Comment: Please could you write it as an answer this is what I was looking for thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to call `newTrip` function, you can do that like this : `myContract.newTrip.sendTransaction(zonesArray[0], zonesArray[1], zonesArray[2], zonesArray[3], name, startDate, duration, {from: web3.eth.coinbase, value : 120000})`
To unlock your account, use `personal.unlockAccount(eth.coinbase, 'your password', duration)` on your node

Comment: Thanks for this, once this is done the transactions is being mined, then i can retreive the block using web3.eth.getBlock(blockHash); but where is the data that the contract has returned in the JSON ?

Comment: As this is not a constant function, you need to broadcast an Event in your function in contract and you can get the data by watching the event. Check this : http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#events